# How to expand 2 divs vertically in responsive layout?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, vertical-alignment, fluid-layout

I believe I am going to ask a very common question because I have also seen related questions before posting mine, but this is a bit different. Normally I don't face any problem when expanding 2 divs vertically, but now I'm working on an application using bootstrap framework. It's a fluid layout that's why I am facing some problem. Please suggest a solution. This is what I used:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="left">content</div>
  <div class="right">content</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.left{ 
    position:absolute; 
    left:0px; 
    border-right:1px solid #bfc4c9;  
    background:#ebf2f9; 
    width:280px !important;
}

.right{ 
    display:block;  
    float:left; 
    position:relative;  
    padding-right:9px; 
    margin-left:300px;  

}
```

I want to align both left and right divs vertically. Content is goes into right div so I want the left panel height to grow with the height of right panel, and since it's a fluid layout, only the left panel width is fixed so I can't define the width in right panel.

Comment: Hi Imran If you want you can go to my site which has what you need. http://net4.ccs.neu.edu/home/dhruven. It on that page itself it has what you need. but it is difficult by just using CSS, are you open to use JS?

Comment: Well it would be good if I can handle this with CSS, In case JS is necassary then i can use it but i don't have any command over JS. Also the website you suggested to me is a fixed layout. I want to align vertical divs in fluid layout. I dont want to define particular width

Comment: Absolute positioning... !important fixed width... where's the fluid layout? I think you should find another solution if you want to keep it fluid. Or, if you want to continue this way, take in mind that Twitter Bootstrap is incompatible with that kind of styles.

Comment: the layout is fluid, only the left panel (menu section) has the fixed width and the right panel is using the remaining width, i hope you got my point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using position absolute - top, bottom, left, and right - on the left column seems to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/ArbVp/

Needs the main div to be position relative, and a clear added under the columns.

Answer (score 0):

@DBUK:
Due to not having enough reputation points I couldn't add a comment to your post.
I have updated your Fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/ArbVp/50/

In this case it is absolutely not neccessary to use 'float' in any way.
Also some other CSS values ​​are "dispensable" ...! ;-)

Cheers
Gunther